# Why is my Toshiba Satellite L675D laptop not connecting to my HD TV using an HDMI cord?

Tags: hdmi, toshiba-laptop

I'm having a problem connecting my Toshiba Satellite L675 laptop to my Samsung HD TV. I've done it before using an HDMI cord but now, for some odd reason, it's not connecting at all.

My computer screen before would go completely black for a second & then come back & (with it being attached to the TV with the HDMI cord & it being on the proper channel) it would make a sound, come on & work beautifully.  Now, I try hooking it up & it doesn't do anything. No black screen, no sound. The TV screen just says there's no connection & that I need to check out the power source.

I'm still checking around, trying to find out if there's a virus in my computer (since my dad & I have the same computer & he can connect his to the TV with no problems), or if  I deleted something that had to do with the connection. I've tried turning my computer off & letting it sit for a while, I've tried checking out other websites & have come up with nothing.

Comment: What happens (when it's plugged in) when you press the display switch ? http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1280&bih=903&tbm=isch&tbnid=U4l1F8LJryJKdM:&imgrefurl=http://www.besly.de/menu/search/archiv/sys/externalmonitor_eng.html&docid=H-OUiah9NLIWpM&imgurl=http://www.besly.de/menu/search/archiv/sys/externalmonitor/externalmonitor.jpg&w=800&h=600&ei=LUdQUJKhBaej0QXF0oCoCg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=192&vpy=596&dur=923&hovh=194&hovw=259&tx=134&ty=138&sig=100216268880111563625&page=3&tbnh=152&tbnw=203&start=46&ndsp=25&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:46,i:220

Answer (score 1):

Often laptops have an ability to cycle through screen connection options - on yours, I think it's FN + F5 (Function Key, lower left hand corner of the keyboard, + the 'F5' key).  This cycles through the power-on display options (only the first option is available when you do not have an external monitor attached) (the last option is available only if you are in Extended Display Mode).

Possibilities:
❖ Built-in display only
❖ Built-in display and external monitor (simultaneously)
❖ External monitor only
❖ Built-in display and TV (or other external video device)
❖ TV (or other external video device)
❖ External monitor and TV
❖ Built-in display and external monitor (extended mode)
❖ Built-in display and TV (extended mode)
❖ External monitor and TV (extended mode)
❖ Swap-Switch primary display between internal display and external monitor when using extended desktop.

This answer was in your laptop's manual.